# Why can't I click a point in an area chart if it is covered by another series?

Tags: charts, highcharts, area, clickable

I created an example from the default area chart, where I display a popup when I click on a point: https://jsfiddle.net/spqbyd8v/2/

```
plotOptions: {
    area: {
        pointStart: 1940,
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            symbol: 'circle',
            radius: 2,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: {
      cursor: 'pointer',
      point: {
        events: {
          click: (event) => alert('clicked')
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The Problem is, that when I click on USA over 1990 (or any other point that is covered by the USSR/Russia series), nor the pointer setting, nor the click event work.

This seems like a strange behavior. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @ppotaczek I am not sure... the example does not work. I also need the point in the callback function, because I use its values for a function call.

Comment: Hi @Martinator, The example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o8zqpt6d/ seems to work in the way you want. You can `this` in the event callback function to refer to a point.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. Thank you, it works as expected. The radius value did not match the value I used, but I just used a fixed value. I will add the answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @ppotaczek, I added code, which checks if one has clicked near a point:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        trackByArea: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    console.log(this)
                    // getting x, y where the user clicked
                    const group = this.series.group;
                    const x = event.chartX - this.plotX - group.translateX;
                    const y = event.chartY - this.plotY - group.translateY;
                    const d = (x * x + y * y);

                    // setting constant radius for click
                    const r = 5;

                    // checking if click happened near point
                    if (d <= r * r) {
                        that.createChartEvent(event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for both the pointer setting and the event.